# How to share resolve between two views (ui-router)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So, I know I can probably create a service, but this would be a lot cleaner and I feel like it should work. I'm trying to inject the resolve from the abstract view, into each controller but I'm getting an injection error. Any ideas? Or is this just not possible?

```
.state('myState', {
        url:'/mystate',
        views:{
            '': {
                templateUrl: 'abstract-view.html',
                 resolve: {
                    myResolve: function(){
                        //resolvey stuff
                    }
                }
            },
            'view-one': {
                templateUrl:'view-one.html',
                controller:'ViewOneCtrl',
            },
            'view-two': {
                templateUrl:'view-two.html',
                controller:'ViewTwoCtrl',
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And... I feel dumb. My resolve needed to be on the state, duh. Not on the view